# TSQL - compare adjacent rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a windows event log imported into a table.  The log contains a record for each web server request and response with a datetime stamp.  Usually the request and response records are adjacent to each other but occasionally there are 2 requests and then 2 responses.  I would like a query that would calculate the average response time, which is the response datetime - the request datetime.

[image: sample table data]

Comment: Is the response `ID` always one more than the corresponding request `ID`? Have you made an attempt that we can help you with?

Comment: sql-server2008 or sql-sever2012? This is one of the few times where it is insanely relevant because of LEAD/TRAILING.

Comment: Habo - I have attempted to self join on id+1 but that doesnt allow for the occasional instances where there are 2 requests then 2 responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the request and response will always be next to each other, get the responses and join to the requests based on the ID+1:

```
SELECT l.ID, l.[date and time] AS [Response Date], l2.[date and time] AS [Request Date], DATEDIFF([date and time],l2.[date and time]) AS [Time]  FROM logs AS l
JOIN logs AS l2 ON l.ID=l2.ID+1
WHERE l.request=0 AND l2.request=1
```

Comment: yea this is great, thank you, any thoughts on how to handle the situation where there are 2 requests and then 2 responses?  I'm trying to figure out how I can somehow first "pair" requests with responses, then do something like this

Comment: Maybe add another column to the table named response_id then create a trigger for the table and have it assign response_id equal to the last request id.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a comment too long to fit in it properly place.

If there's alway a response for a request in a period you can easy calculate the arithmetic median of the time to response by summing all request times, summing all response times and just subtracting the first from the second ans dividing by the number of request (or responses).

It's possible because since you want the average time of all you dont need to pair responses and requests.

Example:

```
T0 - Tf
--   --
 1 - 11
 2 - 12
 3 - 13
```

The above average difference between T0 and Tf is the same of the below

```
T0 - Tf
--   --
 2 - 11
 1 - 12
 3 - 13
```

So the pseudo code below will work

```
select
(
    (
        sum([date and time])
        from [Mytable]
        where is response
    )
    -
    (
        sum([date and time])
        from [Mytable]
        where is request
    )
)
/
(
   count (rows)
    from [Mytable]
    where is request
)
```

Of course you can wish to remove the duplicates.
That can be simple as select distinct [date and time] if all duplicated requests get a duplicated response. Is  amore complicated duplicate case you can use row number to get the first ocurrence.

Anyway the trick to just sum up the whole batch works for arithmetic median.

Comment: Yea this is a great idea, however for my needs it gets pretty complicated when I need to start slicing and dicing the response times by week, hour, minute etc.  Thanks for taking the time to reply, very OTB solution